# Why image is not appearing in background

Tags: css

Why is the background image in showCase[after header] not appearing. As, the image is in the same directory as I mentioned in the css url(''). I've done each and everything I can do. But, I think there is something wrong in my css code before showCase class.

How I can show background image in showCase class[after header].

```css
/* Global Things */
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.container{
    width : 80%;
    margin : auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
/* Header */
header{
    background-color: darkorange;
    padding : 5px;
    margin : 0px;

}
header .logoDesign{
    font-size:20px;
    float:left;
}
header ul li {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;

}
header ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
}
header ul a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:red;
    padding:5px;
    transition: .5s;

    }
    header nav{
        float:right;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
header .logoDesign .lighter{
        color: #FFDF00;
    }

    /* ShowCase Design*/
.showCase{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 170px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    padding-left:170px;
    background: url('./images/showcase.jpg') no-repeat;
    min-height:150px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.showCase h1{
    line-height:1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Welcome | Faizan Corporation </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
                    <!-- For Logo and links.-->
    <header>  
    <div class = "container">
    <div class = "logoDesign" >
                <h1> <span class = "lighter">Faizan</span> Industries </h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
                      <!-- Let's Try to design Showcase. -->
                      <section class = "showCase" >
              <h1>Affordable Professional Websites</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pellentesque est vel vulputate interdum. Nulla vel ante sit amet tortor dignissim fermentum a vel nunc.</p>
          </section>
                        <!-- Now Newsletter Section. -->   
        <div class = "container">
      <div class = "subButton">
          <form action="nothing.php">
              <p>Subscribe to our Newsletter</p>
              <input type="email" placeholder="Enter You Email">
          <button action = "submit" > Submit </button>
          </form>
      </div>
        </div>
                           <!--small Section.-->
<div class = "container">
                           <section class = "portfolio" >

    <ul>
            <li> <img src="images/logo_brush.png" alt="Graphic Design">
                    <h2>Graphics Designing</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
            </li>
          
            <li> <img src="images/logo_html.png" alt="Graphic Design">
                <h2>HTML 5 Markup</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
            </li>

            <li> <img src="images/logo_css.png" alt="Graphic Design">
                 <h2>CSS and CSS 3</h2>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
            </li>
    </ul>
</section>
<footer>
    <p>Faizan Industries, Copyright &copy; 2019 </p>
</footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the image url is in reference to the path of css ?

Comment: Can you screenshot the directory of the css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this in jsFiddle

Background is applied. The issue likely is that your image url is incorrect.

Open Network tab in chrome, then load the page. You will likely see that url failing to load.

If you replace it with a placeholder.com url, such as https://via.placeholder.com/150 you can see the placeholder image being loaded.

[image: EdgeDev DevTools]

Comment: I'm Your big fan.. Problem is fixed...
I was using url('images/1.jpg')
but the correct is url('../images/1.jpg').